# Excel form - go to last selected value

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I'm trying to get a listbox from an excel form to set focus on the last selected value.

Because the listbox is multiselect, if I use the code below, it will deselect things that i want to remain selected:

```
With Me.listName
    For lsti=0 To .listCount-1
        If .selected(lsti) Then
            lastSelectedIndex = lsti
        End If
    Next
    If lastSelectedIndex >-1 Then
        .listindex = lastSelectedIndex 'this causes other items to become deselected
    End If
End With
```

Is there a way i can set focus to the last selected item, without items being deselected?

Answer (score 1):

In what "event" you put this code? If it is in **_click** or **_change**?
This line of code will re-trigger the event

```
   .listindex = lastSelectedIndex
```

Use this technique:
Declare a module level variable

```
 Option Explicit
 Public mbCancel As Boolean
```

Then use this code

```
 Private Sub myListName_Change() 

    If mbCancel Then Exit Sub

    With myListName
    '
     If lastSelectedIndex >-1 Then
       mbCancel=true
      .listindex = lastSelectedIndex
       mbCancel=false 
     End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks M.R for your idea, but it made me realise i was not calling the function correctly.

I have a second list box that i use as a filer with unique values, and i should change the focus only when using the filter. I was also changing the focus on MouseUp on the main listbox, whitch now with a clear head, makes no sense.

So i used the following code separatelly, to change the focus:

```
Private Sub lstFilter_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'filterMainList
    'addIdsToSelected
    setFocusToLast
End Sub

Sub setFocusToLast()

    Dim indexI, lastSelectedId, currentId
    Dim lstI

    With Me.lstFilter
        indexI = .listIndex
        lastSelectedId = .LIST(indexI, 0)
    End With

    With Me.lstIds
        For lstI = .listCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            currentId = .LIST(lstI, 0)
            If currentId = lastSelectedId Then
                .listIndex = lstI
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```